# Wordpress Multisite: How to use child site permalink in main site

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I want to use permalink of childsite in another childsite or in main site. When I try below code its gives only the current site's post permalink. Can anybuddy gives me any idea for extracting permalink of childsite into another childsite.

echo esc_url( get_permalink($id) );

$id is child site post id.